# How to send ERC20 to 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

How to send ERC20 to 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
I have tried to do this on myetherwallet and it will not send as a transaction, is there a special way to send here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Interact with the contract directly.

Go there : https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts
Copy/paste the contract's address and it's abi, then pick "transfer" and you are good.

Don't forget that you have to check how many decimals the token uses! To calculate what amount you need to enter, do `AMOUNT * 10**DECIMALS`.

Comment: Thanks, another question. When you fill in tokens uint256 section if you wanted to burn 100 would you send 100 or do you need to include the decimal places? Thanks

Comment: edited my answer